# SpotBugs SE_NO_SERIALVERSIONID not triggering

Tags: java, findbugs, spotbugs

I am trying to add SpotBugs to my project specifically for SE_NO_SERIALVERSIONID and after running with effort=max I don't see a single class detected, but we know 10 examples we testing to see if they would get detected... all classes have this pattern

```
public final class SessionInfo implements Serializable
{
...
}
```

so we know clearly that the check should have happened but didn't.

Is there a way to see why or to explicitly enable this check?

EDIT:

I am trying to debug why this isn't triggering and see it should looking at the spotbugs source code https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/blob/master/spotbugs/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/detect/SerializableIdiom.java#L410-L413

When I turn on debug logging I see

```
[spotbugs] Directly implements Serializable: org/apache/cassandra/streaming/SessionInfo
...
 [spotbugs] org.apache.cassandra.streaming.SessionInfo
 [spotbugs]   hasPublicVoidConstructor: false
 [spotbugs]   superClassHasVoidConstructor: true
 [spotbugs]   isExternalizable: false
 [spotbugs]   isSerializable: true
 [spotbugs]   isAbstract: false
 [spotbugs]   superClassImplementsSerializable: false
 [spotbugs]   isGUIClass: false
 [spotbugs]   isEjbImplClass: false
 [spotbugs]   isJSPClass: false
```

Not every variable is logged, but knowing the code being inspected it really should trigger...

Answer (score 1):

In ant I set reportLevel="low", seems that this was getting filtered out